# how to set testCase filter when running xunit from code

Tags: c#, xunit

I am trying to run the tests in Xunit using the assembly runner through the code.

My program accepts the dll file name which contains a set of tests.

I need to run some specific tests from the the dll file. I am not looking at category implementation of Xunit. Need to accept the test case once the discovery is completed.

```
public List<ITestCase> TestCases { get; } = new List<ITestCase>();
```

How to add different test cases to the list?

I hope we need to do the filtering after the call of

```
private void OnDiscoveryComplete(DiscoveryCompleteInfo info) { }
```

But `DiscoveryCompleteInfo` contains only the int values of `TestCasesToRun` and `TestCasesDiscovered`.

How to apply a filter for the tests so that test will be executed according to the filter once `OnDiscoveryComplete` is called?

```
 public IList<TestResponse> ExecuteTest(string AutomationTestSuites)
 {
      try
      {
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting of the tests in {0} ", AutomationTestSuites);
            IEnumerable<Assembly> assembly = GetReferencingAssemblies(AutomationTestSuites);
            Assembly _assembly = assembly.Where(s => s.FullName.Contains(AutomationTestSuites)).FirstOrDefault();
            using (var runner = AssemblyRunner.WithoutAppDomain(_assembly.Location))
            {
                runner.OnDiscoveryComplete = OnDiscoveryComplete;
                runner.OnExecutionComplete = OnExecutionComplete;
                runner.OnTestFailed = OnTestFailed;
                runner.OnTestSkipped = OnTestSkipped;
                runner.OnTestPassed = OnTestPassed;
                _logger.LogInformation("Discovering Tests");
                //Runs the Xunit runner in parallel if parallel is set to True
                //If Max Parallel Threads is set to -1 there is no limit to number of threads for Xunit Runner
                runner.Start(parallel: true, maxParallelThreads: -1);

                finished.WaitOne();

                finished.Dispose();

            }

            return (testResponses);

      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
            _logger.LogError("Exeption in ExecuteTestFunctionality : ", ex);                return (testResponses);
      }
}

public static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetReferencingAssemblies(string assemblyName)
{
      var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
      var dependencies = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries;
      foreach (var library in dependencies)
      {
          if (IsCandidateLibrary(library, assemblyName))
          {
              var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(library.Name));
              assemblies.Add(assembly);
          }
       }
       return assemblies;
}
private static bool IsCandidateLibrary(RuntimeLibrary library, string assemblyName)
{
     return library.Name == assemblyName
          || library.Dependencies.Any(d => d.Name.StartsWith(assemblyName));
}

private void OnDiscoveryComplete(DiscoveryCompleteInfo info)
{
     _logger.LogInformation($"Running {info.TestCasesToRun} of {info.TestCasesDiscovered} tests...");

}

private void OnExecutionComplete(ExecutionCompleteInfo info)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Finished: {info.TotalTests} tests in {Math.Round(info.ExecutionTime, executionTimeRoundOff)}s ({info.TestsFailed} failed, {info.TestsSkipped} skipped)");
    finished.Set();
}

private void OnTestFailed(TestFailedInfo info)
{
    _logger.LogError("Test [FAILED] {0}: {1}", info.TestDisplayName, info.ExceptionMessage);
}
private void OnTestPassed(TestPassedInfo info)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Test [Passed] : {0}", info.MethodName);
}
private void OnTestSkipped(TestSkippedInfo info)
{
    _logger.LogWarning("Test [SKIPPED] {0}: {1}", info.MethodName,info.SkipReason);
}
```

I need to filter testcases from a dll and run only the selected tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The runner contains a `TestCaseFilter` property.

```
runner.TestCaseFilter = this.Filter;
```

```
/// <summary>
/// Filters the specified test case.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="testCase">The test case.</param>
/// <returns><c>true</c> if test case should be executed, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
protected bool Filter(ITestCase testCase)
{
    if(testCase.TestMethod.TestClass.Class.Name.StartsWith("DoNotTest")) 
    {
        return false;
    }
        return true;
    }
```

You can also use the method to track all discovered test cases.